# How to do a two dimensional table (array) and fix errors

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

My outputs are not getting out right, and I'm not too sure how to go about doing a two dimensional array.

I have my outputs follow by the outputs should look like.....

Good example how to set up 2 dimensional table would help, since not sure what I find on line is good plus haven't found a good enough book to explain to an old person terms.

First is my code:

```
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION   SECTION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT    SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

       SELECT INPUT-FILE  ASSIGN TO DATAIN
              ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT OUTPUT-FILE ASSIGN TO DATAOUT
              ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT ERROR-FILE ASSIGN TO DATAOUT2
              ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
  *  INPUT FILE LAYOUT                                          *
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   FD  INPUT-FILE.

   01  INPUT-RECORD.
       05  IR-JOB-NUM                   PIC 9(02).
           88  IR-JOB-NUM-VALID         VALUE 01 THRU 11.
       05  IR-EMP-NUM                   PIC 9(01).
           88  IR-EMP-NUM-VALID         VALUE 1  THRU 4.
       05  IR-NUM-COMPLETE              PIC 9(04).
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03).
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(07).

  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
  *  OUTPUT FILE                                                *
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   FD  OUTPUT-FILE.

   01  OUTPUT-RECORD                    PIC X(80).

  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
  *  ERROR FILE                                                 *
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   FD  ERROR-FILE.

   01  ERROR-RECORD                     PIC X(80).

  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
  *  WORKING STORAGE SECTION                                    *
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 FLAGS-AND-ACCUMALATORS.
       05 END-OF-FILE                   PIC XXX   VALUE "NO".
           88 AT-END-OF-FILE                      VALUE "YES".
       05 ERROR-FLAG                    PIC XXX   VALUE "NO".
       05 BLANK-LINE                    PIC X(80) VALUE SPACES.
       05 LINE-NUM-IR-POSITION          PIC 999   VALUE ZERO.

   01 SUBSCRIPT.
       05 SUB                           PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.


  *---------------------------------------------------------------*
  *   REPORT STRUCTURE                                            *
  *---------------------------------------------------------------*
  *   ERROR HEADER RECORD                                         *
   01  ER-HEADER.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(08) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE "NO.".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(06) VALUE "RECORD".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(05) VALUE "ABOVE".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(33) VALUE SPACES.

  *   ERROR DETAIL RECORD                                         *
   01  ER-DETAIL-LINE.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(06) VALUE SPACES.
       05  DL-ASTERIK                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  DL-LINE-NUM                  PIC ZZ9   VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(09) VALUE SPACES.
       05  DL-ERROR                     PIC X(16) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(09) VALUE SPACES.
       05  DL-ERROR-BIG-NUM             PIC ZZZ9 VALUE SPACES.

  *   ERROR ERROR  RECORD                                         *
   01  ER-ERROR-LINE.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
       05  EL-JOB-NUM                   PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  EL-EMP-NUM                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  EL-NUM-COMPLETE              PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(54) VALUE SPACES.

  *   OUTPUT HEADER RECORD                                        *
   01  OR-HEADER.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE "NO.".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(08) VALUE "LOCATION".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(05) VALUE "  1  ".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(05) VALUE "  2  ".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(05) VALUE "  3  ".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(05) VALUE "  4  ".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(05) VALUE "TOTAL".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.

  *   OUTPUT DETAIL RECORD                                        *
   01  OR-DETAIL-LINE.
     03 OR-DETAIL OCCURS 11 TIMES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-JOB-NUM                   PIC 9(02).
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-LOCATION                  PIC X(08) VALUE "XXXXXXXX".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-EMP1-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-EMP2-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-EMP3-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-EMP4-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-JOB-TOT                   PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.

  *   SUMMARY RECORD                                              *
   01  OR-SUMMARY.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(08) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(06)
                                        VALUE "TOTALS".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(04) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-TOT1-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-TOT2-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-TOT3-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-TOT4-AMT                  PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-TOT-TOT                   PIC 9(05) VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.


   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

  *****************************************************************
  *0000-MAIN-PROCEDURE                                            *
  *****************************************************************

   0000-MAIN-PROCEDURE             SECTION.

       OPEN INPUT   INPUT-FILE
            OUTPUT  OUTPUT-FILE
                    ERROR-FILE.

       PERFORM 1000-INITIALIZE.

       PERFORM UNTIL AT-END-OF-FILE
           READ INPUT-FILE
               AT END
                    MOVE 'YES'  TO END-OF-FILE
               NOT AT END
                    PERFORM 2000-PROCESS
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM.

       PERFORM VARYING SUB FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL SUB > 11
           PERFORM 3000-FINALIZE
       END-PERFORM.

       PERFORM 4000-SUMMARY.

       CLOSE INPUT-FILE
             OUTPUT-FILE
             ERROR-FILE.

       GOBACK.

   0000-EXIT.
       EXIT.
  /
  *****************************************************************
  *1000-INITIALIZE                                                *
  *****************************************************************
  *PURPOSE:    INITIALIZE ALL THE VARIABLES AND                   *
  *            WRITE THE HEADER RECORDS TO THE OUTPUT FILES.      *
  *****************************************************************
   1000-INITIALIZE                 SECTION.

       WRITE ERROR-RECORD     FROM ER-HEADER.
       WRITE ERROR-RECORD     FROM BLANK-LINE.

       WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD    FROM OR-HEADER.
       WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD    FROM BLANK-LINE.

   1000-EXIT.
       EXIT.
  /
   2000-PROCESS                    SECTION.
  *****************************************************************
  *PURPOSE:                                                       *
  *****************************************************************
       MOVE 'NO'                   TO ERROR-FLAG.
       ADD 1                       TO LINE-NUM-IR-POSITION.

       IF NOT IR-JOB-NUM-VALID
           MOVE INPUT-RECORD       TO DL-ERROR
           MOVE LINE-NUM-IR-POSITION
                                   TO DL-LINE-NUM
           MOVE 'YES'              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE ALL '*'            TO EL-JOB-NUM
       END-IF.

       IF NOT IR-EMP-NUM-VALID
           MOVE INPUT-RECORD       TO DL-ERROR
           MOVE LINE-NUM-IR-POSITION
                                   TO DL-LINE-NUM
           MOVE 'YES'              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE ALL '*'            TO EL-EMP-NUM
       END-IF.

       IF ERROR-FLAG = 'NO'
           INSPECT IR-NUM-COMPLETE   REPLACING LEADING
                                     SPACES BY ZEROES
          IF  IR-NUM-COMPLETE      IS NUMERIC
              MOVE IR-JOB-NUM         TO SUB

              IF IR-EMP-NUM = 1
                 ADD IR-NUM-COMPLETE  TO
                                        OR-EMP1-AMT(SUB)
              END-IF

              IF IR-EMP-NUM = 2
                 ADD IR-NUM-COMPLETE  TO
                                        OR-EMP2-AMT(SUB)
              END-IF

              IF IR-EMP-NUM = 3
                 ADD IR-NUM-COMPLETE  TO
                                        OR-EMP3-AMT(SUB)
              END-IF

              IF IR-EMP-NUM = 4
                 ADD IR-NUM-COMPLETE  TO
                                        OR-EMP4-AMT(SUB)
              END-IF
          ELSE
             MOVE INPUT-RECORD     TO DL-ERROR
             MOVE LINE-NUM-IR-POSITION
                                   TO DL-LINE-NUM
             MOVE 'YES'            TO ERROR-FLAG
             MOVE ALL '*'          TO EL-NUM-COMPLETE
       END-IF.


       IF ERROR-FLAG = 'YES'
           IF IR-NUM-COMPLETE > 50
              MOVE ALL '*'         TO DL-ASTERIK
              MOVE IR-NUM-COMPLETE TO DL-ERROR-BIG-NUM
           END-IF

           WRITE ERROR-RECORD      FROM ER-DETAIL-LINE
           WRITE ERROR-RECORD      FROM ER-ERROR-LINE

           MOVE  SPACES            TO   ER-DETAIL-LINE
           MOVE  SPACES            TO   ER-ERROR-LINE
       END-IF.

   2000-EXIT.
       EXIT.
  /
   3000-FINALIZE                   SECTION.
  *****************************************************************
  *PURPOSE:                                                       *
  *****************************************************************
       MOVE SUB                    TO OR-JOB-NUM(SUB).

       ADD OR-EMP1-AMT(SUB)
           OR-EMP2-AMT(SUB)
           OR-EMP3-AMT(SUB)
                                   TO OR-EMP4-AMT(SUB)
                               GIVING OR-JOB-TOT(SUB).

       ADD OR-EMP1-AMT(SUB)        TO OR-TOT1-AMT.
       ADD OR-EMP2-AMT(SUB)        TO OR-TOT2-AMT.
       ADD OR-EMP3-AMT(SUB)        TO OR-TOT3-AMT.
       ADD OR-EMP4-AMT(SUB)        TO OR-TOT4-AMT.
       ADD OR-JOB-TOT(SUB)         TO OR-TOT-TOT.

       IF OR-JOB-TOT(SUB) > 0
          WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD         FROM OR-DETAIL(SUB)
          WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD         FROM BLANK-LINE
       END-IF.

   3000-EXIT.
       EXIT.
  /
   4000-SUMMARY                    SECTION.
  *****************************************************************
  *PURPOSE:                                                       *
  *****************************************************************

       WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD         FROM BLANK-LINE.
       WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD         FROM OR-SUMMARY.

   4000-EXIT.
       EXIT.
```

My output in the Exception report is:
NO.          RECORD               ABOVE

```
      3         0r4000700     03
                **
      6         074000Q00     06
                   ***
  *   7         075075000     07          750
                  *
  *   8         06105 100     08          5 1
                   ***
     10         095000500     10
                  *
  *  12         125999999     12         9999
                ***
     19         08500050      19
                  *
     21         125000899     21
                ***
     23         A01001111     23
                **
```

But should be:
          ERROR REPORT

```
   NO.     CONTENTS          ABOVE

     2     032   200     02
              ****

     3     0r4000700     03
           **

     5     073 73000     05
              ****

     6     074000Q00     06
             ****

*    7     075075000     07    750
           *

     8     06105 100     08
             ****

     9     011 52000     09
              ****

    10     095000500     10
             *

*   12     125999999     12   9999
           ***

    19     08500050      19
             *

*   20     091010000     20    100


    21     125000899     21
           ***

    23     A01001111     23
           **
```

And my output for summary is:

```
NO.  LOCATION     1       2       3       4     TOTAL

  01   XXXXXXXX   00520   00000   00000   00000   00520

  03   XXXXXXXX   00000   00002   00000   00007   00009

  04   XXXXXXXX   00010   00010   00003   00000   00023

  05   XXXXXXXX   00000   00012   00000   00004   00016

  06   XXXXXXXX   00000   00000   00000   00004   00004

  07   XXXXXXXX   00000   00000   00730   00000   00730

  08   XXXXXXXX   00006   00000   00000   00004   00010

  09   XXXXXXXX   00100   00000   00000   00000   00100


        TOTALS    00636   00024   00733   00019   01412
```

And should look like this:

```
  SUMMARY REPORT

  NO.     LOCATION                   1         2         3         4      TOTAL

    1     PETERS,           FL       0         0         0         0          0

    2     ATCHISON,         KS       0         0         0         0          0

    3     KANSAS CITY,      MO       0         0         0         7          7

    4     DENVER,           CO      10        10         3         0         23

    5     SAN JOSE,         CA       0        12         0         4         16

    6     REDMOND,          WA       0         0         0         4          4

    7     HOUSTON,          TX       0         0         0         0          0

    8     TOPEKA,           KS       6         0         0         4         10

    9     WICHITA,          KS     100         0         0         0        100

   10     JEFFERSON CITY,   MO       0         0         0         0          0

   11     ST. LOUIS         MO       0         0         0         0          0

          TOTALS                   116        22         3        19        160
```

Comment: Preferably install the latest GnuCOBOL which you'll locate at SourceForge.net. GnuCOBOL is the new name for OpenCOBOL. Also locate Gary Cutler's Programmer's Guide for OpenCOBOL 1.1 or GnuCOBOL 2.0 and see if that tells you what you need to know. There are also discussion areas at the GnuCOBOL area of SourceForge, no question too small.

Comment: You'll need editing PICtures to get the zero-suppression for your output, ie PIC Z(4)9.

Comment: Nicely formatted. You should identify all the errors, then only do the adds for the good ones. Look at your "complex" add, and find the confusion. You can use VARYING on a PERFORM of a paragraph/SECTION, you don't need to wrap an in-line PERFORM around it. Since you always know how many there are, consider PERFORM ... TIMES and increment SUB in the procedure. Your comments are a bit pointless :-)

Answer (score 1):

For **Multi dimensional** arrays in Cobol, just **nest** the occurs clause:

```
   01 WS-DETAIL-totals OCCURS 11 TIMES.
       05  WS-JOB-NUM                   PIC 9(02).
       05  WS-LOCATION                  PIC X(08) VALUE "XXXXXXXX".
       05  WS-EMP-AMT     occurs 4      PIC s9(05) COMP VALUE ZEROES.
       05  WS-JOB-TOT                   PIC s9(05) COMP VALUE ZEROES.


   01  OR-DETAIL-LINE.
     03 OR-DETAIL OCCURS 11 TIMES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-JOB-NUM                   PIC z9.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-LOCATION                  PIC X(08) VALUE "XXXXXXXX".
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  Filler occurs 4.
           10  OR-EMP1-AMT              PIC ----9.
           10  FILLER                   PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
       05  OR-JOB-TOT                   PIC ----9 VALUE ZEROES.
       05  FILLER                       PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
```

You **should** also accumulate in **comp** fields (like in ws table above) and move to output table.

The

```
      INSPECT IR-NUM-COMPLETE   REPLACING LEADING
                                 SPACES BY ZEROES
```

statement in 2000- means errors like the following are not caught

```
     2     032   200     02
              ****
```

Comment: If you use a separate accumulation table and use the ----9 picture clauses like I used in the table example, you will suppress leading zero's like you want in your expected output.